# is there a difference between "last 2 days" and "past 2 days"

Tags: differences

Are "last" and "past" interchangeable in:

- last 2 days
- past 2 days

?

Comment: Pretty similar.  Perhaps 'past' has a stronger sense of 'during'...

Comment: You can't use *"past"* in *"the last two days of this month"* and similar expressions. But aside from that, they're pretty similar.

Comment: If not followed by "of" they are largely interchangeable.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that ***last*** 2 days refers to the 2 days that terminate any period, regardless of where that period is located in time. For example, you can say:

> I felt really bad during the last 2 days of that trip in 1998.

The ***past*** 2 days refers to the 2 days preceding the moment of speaking. So it cannot be used as above.

Since '*last 2 days*' seems a bit more general, you can also use it to indicate the termination of current period, i.e. to refer to the 2 days before the moment of speaking, in which case it becomes equivalent to '*past 2 days*'